# Windows Install of PhantomJS fails

Tags: windows, windows-7, gruntjs, npm, phantomjs

I am attempting to install PhantomJS 1.8.1-3 on windows via npm. It appears to fail regardless of what I do. Here's the command I am running:

```
npm install phantomjs
```

After executing that command, it fails with the following errors:

```
    > phantomjs@1.8.1-3 install c:\johnprojects\tablet\htdocs\mini-app-sandbox\node_
modules\grunt-contrib-qunit\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phanto
mjs
> node install.js

Requesting c:\johnprojects\tablet\htdocs\mini-app-sandbox\node_modules\grunt-con
trib-qunit\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs\tmp\phantomjs
-1.8.1-windows.zip

events.js:71
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:761:19)
npm ERR! phantomjs@1.8.1-3 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node install.js"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs@1.8.1-3 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files
(x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "grunt-contrib-quni
t" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd c:\johnprojects\tablet\htdocs\mini-app-sandbox
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.21
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.32
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message phantomjs@1.8.1-3 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! message `cmd "/c" "node install.js"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     c:\johnprojects\tablet\htdocs\mini-app-sandbox\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: I have the same problem with 1.8.2; downloading the zip and extracting it tells me the crc for phantomjs.exe is invalid; this is my npm log:

https://gist.github.com/ToJans/5169008

Comment: With version 1.9.7-6 yet another possible error is `Error requesting archive. Status: 403`. The workaround is the same as described in the answer by @ashnazg.

Answer (score 2):

Although I could not figure out *why* it was happening, I was able to work around that ECONNREFUSED error from "npm install" during the phantomjs zip file step by just manually downloading the zip file separately, placing it in the tmp directory where the download was attempting to write to.

Comment: This is the right answer. Some kind of download issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

phantomjs isn't yet compatible with node 0.10.   You need 0.08:
https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/986

Comment: This didn't work even when I was on 0.08 - upgrading was one of the methods I tried to resolve this issue.

Comment: it took some effort for me to get a good install of 0.08 working. I think the primary thing is to make sure any issues with `brew doctor` are resolved..

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to a simmular issue while installing grunt-html-snapshot@0.6.1 (html-snapshots => same prob) where phantomjs@1.9.15 is a dependancy.

I didn't get exactly the same error though. Where you got

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

I got

```
Error: EPERM, operation not permitted
```

My problem was a permission issue fixed doing the "BohemMedia" comment you can find on github [HERE](https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/19)

The other approaches did not work for me.

Your problem is a refused connection. Did you try turning off your firewalls and other security programs that could block the connection?

Comment: P.S.: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823319/yeoman-generator-always-get-some-error?nah=1#28738433) post might also be of interest for people who have issues with the phantomjs installation